# Bug in the CAPTCHA at data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, captcha

By mistake while me trying to prove that I am human I pressed enter before I finished the last character (One of my hands was faster; it's cold here.) and it worked; I waited and tried it again (twice more) to confirm it and it actually works. I am not sure whatever I can miss more than one character, but surely I can one character.

Comment: Wondering whatever it's duplicate, because of that downvote.

Comment: Probably someone who assumed you're trolling...which appearantly you're not....

Comment: I'm curious as to why you posted about it here, rather than on data's meta or (more appropriately) the overall SE meta.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I didn't knew there was such thing, until now.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I tried http://meta.data.stackexchange.com and nothing's there; care to post a valid link?

Comment: Just kidding, apparently data.SE is bizarre and doesn't have a meta. Ignore me on that one. :)  meta.SE might still be a better home.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is refreshing; usually folks complain about the CAPTCHAs being *too hard*!

Anyway, you can get some parts wrong because your answers are being used to help [recognize text that isn't already known](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html):

> reCAPTCHA offers more than just spam protection. Every time our CAPTCHAs are solved, that human effort helps digitize text, annotate images, and build machine learning datasets. This in turn helps preserve books, improve maps, and solve hard AI problems.

Of course, you do have to get at least *part* of the CAPTCHA right, and there's no guarantee which part that is.

Comment: To add: The way that the computer determines whether the answer is correct or not is that inserts an actual captcha in combination with the unknown text. If you get *that* part correct, your *entire* answer is considered correct, even though you got the unknown part wrong. The same unknown part is given to many other testers to determine a confidence level. The only problem is that *you don't know which is the captcha, and which one's the real text*.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Sometimes it can be pretty obvious, like when one is computer generated, and the other an image of a house number.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, but I see a image with letter *bg*, and I passed the checking by just enter *o*...

Comment: @Scimonster That's why I used *italics* to indicate the possible sarcasm...some people just don't understand it.

Comment: Here is the URL for the text quoted above  in case anyone wants to do some further reading. http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Italics convey emphasis, not necessarily sarcasm.  It's not that "some people just don't understand it", it's just that you're bad at communicating it.

Comment: @Scimonster Well, not necessarily. What if the house number if already converted with a high enough confidence, enabling it to be used as the actual captcha?

Comment: is this part of the semantic web? *is there official markup for sarcasm?* .

Comment: `;)`I suppose so `;)`, @KarolyHorvath